# Kendo UI Scheduler Edit pop up window wont close after making changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, telerik

I am trying out the Kendo UI HTML Scheduler. 
I was able to successfully read appointments from the database through my ASP.NET MVC appplication.

For Read : I am sending JsonResult from my ASP.NET controller.

For Update : The controller is getting a URL JSON encoded string which I deserialize and update the database and the return nothing to the caller.

When open an event to edit, make the changes and press "Save". The controller gets called and the record is updated but neither the pop-up window closes nor the scheduler gets updated.

The HTML Demo on Telerik website returns "callback()" on update and works fine but what am I missing on my code that would make the changes reflect.

```
**view**
<script>
   $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
           // configuration //
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url : "http://localhost/Scheduler/Appointments",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {
                    Type:"POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/Scheduler/UpdateAppointment",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: JSON.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
            },  
            schema: {
                model: {
                     // my model 
                }
            },
</script>
```

**Controller** 
public JsonResult UpdateAppointment(String models)
        {

```
  if (models != null)
     {
      char[] charsToTrim = { '[', ']' };
      string model_Trimmed = models.Trim(charsToTrim);

      // Deserialize
      Appointment SerializedAppointment = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Appointment>(model_Trimmed);

      Models.Entities.Appointment AppointmentToUpdate = db.Appointment.Where(x => x.TaskID == SerializedAppointment.TaskID).Single();

            AppointmentToUpdate.Title = SerializedAppointment.Title;
            AppointmentToUpdate.Start = SerializedAppointment.Start;
            AppointmentToUpdate.End = SerializedAppointment.End;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
  return new JsonResult() {Data=null, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Kendo needs to return a valid JSON format in your paramater map, so you could try this:

```
        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return {models: JSON.stringify(options.models)};
            }
            return {};
        }
```

Maybe [this Link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/update-destroy-operations-trigger-the-error-event-of-the-datasource-after-updating-to-q1-2013-%28v-2013-1-319%29) will also helps you...

(Copy just to prevent dead Links)

There is a breaking change with the new version of jQuery which affects the Kendo Q1 2013 version 2013.1.319

Since the empty result returned from the server in case everything is executed properly on the server side for the update and destroy requests, the error event of the dataSource is triggered because the empty result is not valid JSON.

The suggested resolutions when using the MVC Extensions are:
Use the Latest Internal Build version 2013.1.327
Change the response of the Update/Destroy actions from just serializing the ModelState to:

```
return Json(ModelState.IsValid ? new object(): ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
```